# JDBC connection pool to multiple MySQL databases on the same server (with the same user and password)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, c3p0, pool

I have multiple websites (about 200) that are hosted by the same Java web app.  Each site has its own MySQL database.  The databases are all on the same MySQL server and are all accessed with the same user name and password.

I'm currently running out of database connections because of the way that I have implemented pooling.  I'm using a C3P0 ComboPooledDataSource for each site's database.  This creates hundreds of connections to the database server, and the database server just can't seem to handle it.

Is there a pooling mechanism that creates a pool of database connections that can be used for all the databases hosted on a single database server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I can create a ComboPooledDataSource for the first database.  Then when I get a connection from the database pool, I can call `setCatalog(name)` on the connection to use any other database on the same server using [C3P0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/) data pooling.

```
ComboPooledDataSource cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
cpds.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
cpds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/site_a");
cpds.setUser(user);
cpds.setPassword(pass);
....
Connection conn = getPool().getConnection();
conn.setCatalog("site_b");
...
```

Edit: Since writing this post I switched to  [Proxool](http://proxool.sourceforge.net/).  The same technique of `setCatalog` works for it, but the syntax for creating a connection is different:

```
try {
    Class.forName("org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.ProxoolDriver");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
Properties info = new Properties();
info.setProperty("proxool.maximum-connection-count", "20");
info.setProperty("proxool.house-keeping-test-sql", " select CURDATE()");
info.setProperty("user", user);
info.setProperty("password", pass);
info.setProperty("proxool.alias", "mypoolname");
info.setProperty("proxool.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/site_a");
info.setProperty("proxool.driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
String url = "proxool.mypoolname";
ProxoolDatabasePool pool = new ProxoolDatabasePool(url, info);
....
Connection conn = pool.getConnection();
conn.setCatalog("site_b");
...
```

Comment: Hey, is that ComboPooledDataSource class a thrid party library or...?

Comment: Thanx for that. will look it up.